# phpunit configuration file doesn't load - Uncaught PHPUnit\Util\Xml\Exception

Tags: phpunit

I have a phpunit.xml file in the root of my project. When I run `vendor/bin/phpunit web/core/tests/Drupal/KernelTests/Core/DependencyInjection/AutowireTest.php`, this file is picked up and the tests run correctly. I can confirm that happens because the tests run, and because if I remove the file, phpunit crashes.

I've made an exact copy of that file and named it `phpunit-host.xml`.

If I do `vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit-host.xml web/core/tests/Drupal/KernelTests/Core/DependencyInjection/AutowireTest.php` then everything crashes:

```
PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Util\Xml\Exception: Could not read "phpunit-host.xml". in /Users/joachim/Sites/drupal-core-development-project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Xml/Loader.php:49
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/joachim/Sites/drupal-core-development-project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/XmlConfiguration/Loader.php(71): PHPUnit\Util\Xml\Loader->loadFile('phpunit-host.xm...', false, true, true)
#1 Standard input code(101): PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Loader->load('phpunit-host.xm...')
#2 {main}

Next PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Exception: Could not read "phpunit-host.xml". in /Users/joachim/Sites/drupal-core-development-project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/XmlConfiguration/Loader.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 Standard input code(101): PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Loader->load('phpunit-host.xm...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/joachim/Sites/drupal-core-development-project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/XmlConfiguration/Loader.php on line 73
Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit\Util\Xml\Exception: Could not read "phpunit-host.xml". in /Users/joachim/Sites/drupal-core-development-project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Xml/Loader.php:49
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/joachim/Sites/drupal-core-development-project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/XmlConfiguration/Loader.php(71): PHPUnit\Util\Xml\Loader->loadFile('phpunit-host.xm...', false, true, true)
#1 Standard input code(101): PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Loader->load('phpunit-host.xm...')
#2 {main}

Next PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Exception: Could not read "phpunit-host.xml". in /Users/joachim/Sites/drupal-core-development-project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/XmlConfiguration/Loader.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 Standard input code(101): PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Loader->load('phpunit-host.xm...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/joachim/Sites/drupal-core-development-project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/XmlConfiguration/Loader.php on line 73
```

What is going wrong?

I've tried looking in vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Xml/Loader.php and getcwd() and the $filename all match up, and $contents is the XML string of the file.

Comment: I think that the path to the XML is not correct. therefore file_get_contents() cannot read the file. The exception is then thrown by false. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/18a76cf7293527f275342720eeb063dff346c97e/src/Util/Xml/Loader.php#L37

Comment: I put in a dump(file_get_contents()) in vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Xml/Loader.php and that outputs the XML.

Comment: Which PHPUnit version are you using?

Comment: 9.6.13. Sorry, should have said in the post.

Comment: Because [$contents is false](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/f3d767f7f9e191eab4189abe41ab37797e30b1be/src/Util/Xml/Loader.php#L37), the exception is thrown. That is what I can see from the exception. I can't do more now because I can't debug the code myself. What have you done in the method? The line number no longer matches the PHPUnit source.

Comment: The line numbers don't match because I put in a ton of dump() statements to try to understand the problem, as the exception message is lacking in detail. $contents is not false at that point -- it contains the XML string.

Comment: That's what I thought. But if you only inserted a dump() and didn't change anything else, I don't know what to do. Without being able to debug it myself, I can't help you.

Comment: I suspect the code comes round the same place twice and is FALSE the second time, but I wasn't managing to see the FALSE $content being output. Also, this is on DDEV where I haven't yet attempted to set up xdebug.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue while running tests with a phpunit.xml file placed in the root and using -c option. Running the tests with the full path of the file fixed this. I assume it's looking for the exact string and can't find it when called from the module with the tests.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit -c /var/www/html/phpunit-new.xml
```